# Slow database queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Since my website database has grown very large the performance for certain queries has become terrible. Some queries are taking over 30 seconds to perform. I'm wondering if someone can help me optimize my query or make a suggestion on how I can improve performance? I have set an index on all the foreign keys and ids.

```
SELECT p.*
     , u.unique_id
     , u.nick_name
     , u.avatar_thumb
     , t.desc as tag_desc
     , pt.post_id as tag_post_id 
  from tt_post_tags pt
  LEFT 
  JOIN tt_posts p
    ON p.id = pt.post_id
 RIGHT 
  JOIN tt_users u 
    ON p.user_id = u.user_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN tt_tags t
    ON t.name = "gameday"
 WHERE pt.name = "gameday"
 ORDER 
    BY create_date DESC
 LIMIT 100
```

The above query takes 29 seconds to complete. If I remove the "create_date DESC" from the query it runs in .3 seconds. I've added an index to create_date but still, it takes 30 seconds for the query to run. The tt_posts table contains about 1.6 million records.

My database has the following tables: Posts, Users, Tags, and PostTags.

**Posts table** contains a foreign key for the users table.

**Tags table** contains a unique id and name for each tag

**Post_tags table** contains the foreign key from the Tags table aswell as a foreign key for the post that the tag is for.

I can include a diagram tomorrow if it's not easy to understand. Hopefully, someone can assist me. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE `tt_posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `cover` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `create_date` (`create_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4641550 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[image: Explain select]

```
CREATE TABLE `tt_tags` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tt_tag_id` BIGINT(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`name`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `tt_tag_id` (`tt_tag_id`),
    INDEX `tt_tag_id_key` (`tt_tag_id`),
    INDEX `name_key` (`name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE `tt_post_tags` (
    `post_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    INDEX `post_id` (`post_id`),
    INDEX `name` (`name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE `tt_users` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` BIGINT(30) NOT NULL,
    `unique_id` VARCHAR(190) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `nick_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `avatar` VARCHAR(190) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `signature` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `unique_id` (`unique_id`),
    INDEX `unique_id_index` (`unique_id`),
    INDEX `user_id_index` (`user_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: without going into the specifics of the language, this question is about the logistics. think about what the query is actually doing and how you can reduce the intensity of the load. if the code has too many conditions, can you reduce them by adding to your WHERE condition?

Comment: in providing a hint: `WHERE create_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2` should substantially reduce your query time.

Comment: Have you seen an owl turn its head almost completely around.  That's what I feel like when I see a query with both `RIGHT` and `LEFT` joins.  Could you rewrite it to avoid `RIGHT`?

Comment: And please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I  _must_ know which table it is in in order to help you.

Comment: And provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: Without the EXPLAIN, we can't really help

Comment: @rick-james I've added the information that you requested. I usually don't do much in the real of complicated MySQL queries so I'm doing what I know. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Hmmm....  Small values in "rows"; "eq_ref", "const" -- It should have taken more than a few milliseconds.  Is this really a "slow" query?

Comment: Oh.  How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @rick-james I took that from my development server which has a fraction of the rows that my production server has. Production has 1814072 rows for that query. The server has 8GB of ram.

Comment: @EliseCrane - OK.  After you reformulate it without a `RIGHT`, I'll dig further.  (No, I don't want to start with Thorsten's formulation with the derived table in a `LEFT JOIN`.  Maybe, if you can explain what the query is supposed to provide, I can start from scratch.

Comment: @rick-james essentially what I am trying to get is all of the posts under a certain hashtag and joining the users associated with each post.

Comment: @EliseCrane - Let's focus on the first part: "the posts under a certain hashtag".  That is, see if you can write a minimal SQL to achieve that -- without worrying about the "associated users".  The will do 2 things -- you will check how fast that runs; I will look for ways to make it run faster.  After that, we can see how to tack on the associated users.

Comment: @rick-james `select tt_posts.*, tt_post_tags.post_id as tag_post_id from tt_post_tags
inner join tt_posts on tt_posts.id=tt_post_tags.post_id
inner join tt_tags on tt_tags.name = "gameday"
where tt_post_tags.name = "gameday"` returns my query in 0.156 sec. Once I add the order by clause on the end it takes 15+ seconds.

Comment: @EliseCrane - Just `ORDER BY`?  Or do you mean `LIMIT` also?  In either case, let's work on that statement without `users`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the main issue with your query is the mix of left and right outer joins. Honestly, are you able to read this correctly?

The first join alone seems weird. You outer join a post to its post tags. But can a post tag without a post even exist? What would it refer to? (The other way round would make more sense: to also select posts that have no tags.) If I am not mistaken here, your join is rendered to a mere inner join. In your where clause you further limit this result to post tags named 'gameday'.

Then you right outer join users. We avoid right outer joins for being by far less readable than left outer joins, but well, you select all users, even those without 'gameday' post tags here.

Then you left outer join all 'gameday' tags. This looks completely unrelated to the other tables (i.e. you either find 'gameday' tags or not). But in your explanation you say "Post_tags table contains the foreign key from the Tags", so I surmise there is no tag_id in your post tags table, but the name is the tag ID really (and thus also the foreign key in your post tags table). This again leads to the question: Why would a post tag even exist, when it has no related tag? Probably this is not possible, and again all this is boiled down to a mere inner join. (I would recommend here to have a `tag_id` instead of the names in both tables, just for readability. The column name `name` kind of hides the foreign key relationship.)

In your query, you don't show any information of the post tags table, but I see you select `pt.post_id as tag_post_id`, which of course is just `p.id as tag_post_id` again. I suppose this is a typo and you want to show `pt.id as tag_post_id` instead?

I understand that you want to see all users, but are only interested in 'gameday' post tags. This makes writing the query a little complicated. I would probably just select users and outer join the complete post tag information.

Your `create_date` is not qualified with a table. I suppose it is a column in the posts table?

This is the query I am coming up with:

```
select
  gdp.*,
  u.unique_id,
  u.nick_name,
  u.avatar_thumb
from tt_users u 
left join
(
  select
    p.*,
    t.desc as tag_desc,
    pt.id as tag_post_id
  from tt_tags t
  join tt_post_tags pt on pt.name = t.name
  join tt_posts p on p.id = pt.post_id
  where t.name = 'gameday'
) gdp on gdp.user_id = u.user_id
order by p.create_date desc;
```

There has been a lot of guessing on my side, so this query may still be a little different from what you need. I don't know.

Now let's look at which table columns are accessed, to provide good indexes for the query. Let's particularily look at the subquery where we collect all post tags:

1. We only want 'gameday' tags. As this seems to be the primary key for tt_tags, there should already be a unique index on `tt_tags(name)`.
2. Being the foreign key, there should also be an index on `tt_post_tags(name)`. This is good, but as we want to continue joining on the `post_id`, it would be beneficial to have this in the index, too: `create unique index idx on tt_post_tags(name, post_id)`. However, as this is the table's natural key, this index should also already exist in order to ensure data integrity. If it doesn't exist yet, hurry up to provide it.
3. At last we join `tt_posts` on its primary key (i.e. there should be an index on `tt_posts(id)`). Once more: Nothing for us to do here.

You select all users and you select all 'gameday' tags. Then you must join all found tags to the users, which already is some work. You can imagine this as ordering all found tags by `user_id` first in order to join. Then you want to sort your result by post date. This means that the DBMS must again sort all result rows. Sorting takes time; that's just the way it is. How many rows does the result contain? If we are talking about millions of rows to sort, then this will probably remain slow. And if many post tags are 'gameday' tags, then even the indexes may not help much reading the tables and the DBMS may go for full sequential table reads instead. Make sure the statistics are up-to-date (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I will look into this further later today when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

(Iteration one of Answering the Question)

First, let's look at the query without `users`:

```
select  p.id
    from  post_tags AS pt
    join  posts     AS p   ON p.id = pt.post_id
    join  tags      AS t   ON t.name = "gameday"
    where  pt.name = "gameday"
    ORDER BY p.create_date
    LIMIT 100;
```

It is not possible to have a single index that handles both `pt.name` and `p.create_date`.  Is there any way to get them into the same table?  I see, for example, that `name` seems to be redundantly in `t` and `p`.

`tt_post_tags` sounds like a many-to-many mapping table between posts and tags; is it?  If so, what is `name`, the seems to be in `tags` and `post_tags`?

I think this

```
 join  tags      AS t   ON t.name = "gameday"
```

should be

```
 join  tags      AS t   ON t.name = "gameday"  AND pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
```

If so, that might be the main problem.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the rest of the tables.

The following indexes may (or may not) help:

```
tags:  (post_id, name)
tags:  (name, tag_id)
posts:  (create_date, id)
post_tags:  (name, post_id)
```

**More**

A `UNIQUE INDEX` is an `INDEX`, so the second of these is redundant and should be dropped:  `UNIQUE(x), INDEX(x)`

Index Cookbook:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: I've added the other create statements for the other tables. Yes, tags and post_tag is a many to many relationship. The name column in post_tags is the way I connect to the tags table. I guess I could have used the tag id but used the name. I'm trying to alter my database now but adding the multi-column index you mentioned are taking forever.

Comment: I added more about indexes.

Comment: I think my idea with the name column bein duplicated in the two tables was to be able to get just the posts under associated with a specific tag without needing to join the third table. After leaving the create index command for about an hour MySQL gave me the following error. `ERROR 1061 (42000): Duplicate key name 'name_post_id` and the command I ran was `ALTER TABLE 'tt_post_tags'  ADD INDEX 'name_post_id' ('name', 'post_id');`

Comment: @EliseCrane - Check `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- looks like you might have already added that index?